# Hot to "pass" OLDROW and NEWROW to Stored Procedure in DB2 trigger?

Tags: stored-procedures, triggers, db2-400

I have a bunch of triggers on tables in DB2 for the iseries. They are directly writing to other tables, but I've been asked to change them so that the triggers instead call something else to do the writing.

This something else part is a little vague I know. I would imagine I can't call a trigger from another trigger (correct me if I am wrong), so I imagine it has to be a stored procedure. Is there such a thing as something like a "program" in DB2 that I could call instead?

Assuming it is a stored procedure, how do I pass in the OLDROW and NEWROW to be handled in the SP?

For example, the trigger could look something like this (stripped down of course):

```
CREATE TRIGGER MYSCHEMA.WHATEVERTABLE_AFTER_INSERT_TRIGGER
AFTER INSERT ON MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE
REFERENCING NEW AS NEWROW
FOR EACH ROW 
MODE DB2ROW 
SET OPTION  ALWBLK = *ALLREAD , 
ALWCPYDTA = *OPTIMIZE , 
COMMIT = *CS , 
DECRESULT = (31, 31, 00) , 
DFTRDBCOL = *NONE , 
DYNDFTCOL = *NO , 
DYNUSRPRF = *USER , 
SRTSEQ = *HEX   
WHEN ( 1 = 1 ) 

BEGIN ATOMIC

INSERT INTO NEWSCHEMA.NEWTABLE
(
AAA,
BBB,
CCC
)
VALUES
(
NEWROW.AAA,
NEWROW.BBB,
NEWROW.CCC
);

END;
```

The trigger just need to replicate a table most of the time, so I need access to OLDROW sometimes, and NEWROW other times, and sometimes both. However, I believe these only make sense in context of the trigger, so how do I pass this info to the SP?

Answer (score 0):

On DB2 for IBM i...

Every stored procedure IS a program and vice versa.  One of the many benefits of having an OS that is a DB.

I'm pretty sure you can't call a stored procedure from an SQL trigger and pass the entire NEWROW implicitly.  You could try

```
CALL MYSP (NEWROW.*);
```

You might be able to use dynamic SQL to query the meta data and build a dynamic call

But even if one of those works, you'd probably shouldn't do it.  Because now you've got a dependency between the called SP and the structure of the table (like you'd have with old fashioned RPG).  One of the reasons to use SQL is to avoid that dependency.

Now, if you where using RPG or COBOL to define your trigger, then it's pretty easy to pass around the 
pointer to the trigger buffer the DB provides to the program.  But RPG & COBOL are lower level languages compared to SQL.

What's the reason for asking for the "something else" to do the writing?